# How to parse quantifier expressions in Z3/Java?

Tags: java, z3

In the following example, I want to parse the expression.
Please make me aware of the Z3 methods for doing so.
(In my application, I get an expression simplified by Z3.)

```
import com.microsoft.z3.*;

public class Z3_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Context context = new Context();
        Expr quantified;
        {
            BoolExpr b1 = context.mkBoolConst("b1");
            BoolExpr b2 = context.mkBoolConst("b2");
            BoolExpr body = context.mkIff(b1, b2);
            quantified = context.mkQuantifier(
                    true,
                    new Expr[]{b1},
                    body,
                    0,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
        }
        System.out.println(quantified);
        {
            if (quantified.isQuantifier()) {
                System.out.println("quantifier");
                System.out.println("quantified.getNumArgs() = " + quantified.getNumArgs());

                // following two lines result in "com.microsoft.z3.Z3Exception: invalid argument"
                // quantified.getArgs();
                // Quantifier casted = (Quantifier) quantified;
            } else {
                System.out.println("no quantifier");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[z3/C++ related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820361/how-to-visit-z3-expressions-with-quantifiers)

Please also have a look at the extended example [integrating the approach of alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63082468/4474457) where the condition is simplified in between. The `Expr output` obtained from the simplification can't be casted to a `Quantifier` although it satisfies `.isQuantifier()`.

The variable `ENABLE_ERROR` can be used to switch the casting error on and off.

```
import com.microsoft.z3.*;

public class Z3_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final boolean ENABLE_ERROR = true;
        Context context = new Context();
        Expr input;
        {
            BoolExpr b1 = context.mkBoolConst("b1");
            BoolExpr b2 = context.mkBoolConst("b2");
            BoolExpr body = context.mkIff(b1, b2);
            input = context.mkQuantifier(
                    true,
                    new Expr[]{b1},
                    body,
                    0,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
        }
        System.out.println("input = " + input);
        Expr output = input;
        if (ENABLE_ERROR) {
            Goal g4 = context.mkGoal(true, false, false);
            g4.add((BoolExpr) input);
            Params params = context.mkParams();
            ApplyResult ar = context.mkTactic("simplify").apply(g4, params);
            output = ar.getSubgoals()[0].AsBoolExpr();
        }
        System.out.println("output = " + output);
        {
            if (output.isQuantifier()) {
                System.out.println("quantifier");
                System.out.println("output.getNumArgs() = " + output.getNumArgs());
                Quantifier casted = (Quantifier) output;
                int i = casted.getNumBound();
                System.out.println("casted.getNumBound() = " + i);
                for (int c = 0; c < i; c++) {
                    System.out.println("casted.getBoundVariableNames(" + c + ") = " + casted.getBoundVariableNames()[c]);
                }
                System.out.println("casted.getBody() = " + casted.getBody());
            } else {
                System.out.println("no quantifier");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `mkQuantifier` returns a `Quantifier`, which is not an expression by itself. (It contains an expression in the body, of course.)

You can write your example like this:

```java
import com.microsoft.z3.*;

public class Z3_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Context context = new Context();
        Expr quantified;
        {
            BoolExpr b1 = context.mkBoolConst("b1");
            BoolExpr b2 = context.mkBoolConst("b2");
            BoolExpr body = context.mkIff(b1, b2);
            quantified = context.mkQuantifier(
                    true,
                    new Expr[]{b1},
                    body,
                    0,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
        }
        System.out.println(quantified);
        {
            if (quantified.isQuantifier()) {
                System.out.println("quantifier");

                /* Cast to Quantifier first */
                Quantifier q = (Quantifier) quantified;
                int i = q.getNumBound();
                System.out.println("q.getNumBound()            = " + i);
                for (int c = 0; c < i; c++) {
                    System.out.println("q.getBoundVariableNames(" + c + ") = " + q.getBoundVariableNames()[c]);
                }
                System.out.println("q.getBody()                = " + q.getBody());
            } else {
                System.out.println("no quantifier");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
(forall ((b1 Bool)) (! (= b1 b2) :weight 0))
quantifier
q.getNumBound()            = 1
q.getBoundVariableNames(0) = b1
q.getBody()                = (= (:var 0) b2)
```

which shows you how to dive into the quantifier itself. The crucial point is to cast the expression to a quantifier before diving in.

Also note that the bound-variables are internally renamed, that's why you see `(:var 0)` instead of `b1` which you might otherwise expect.

Comment: Your solution depends on the fact that the variable `quantified` is now of type `Quantifier`. In my application, I am simplifying an expression and then want to parse it back. Hence, there is some black box in between creating and parsing of the expression and I therefore believe that this solution does not work for me. I am wondering why the `Expr quantified` can't be casted into a `Quantifier` in my example above since `Quantifier` extends `BoolExpr`, which in turn extends `Expr`. Storing the `Quantifier` in the variable `quantified` should allow for casting it back to `Quantifier`?

Comment: @RonnieMarksch You should be able to cast it just fine. See my modified answer which starts with `Expr quantified;` and properly casts it right before diving in using `Quantifier q = (Quantifier) quantified;`.

Comment: This is true. However, it does not work with my extended example from above where the `Expr` is changed in between using simplification (although it appears to have not).

Comment: Your modified program works just fine for me when I compile it. The only issue I see is in the line `System.out.println("output.getNumArgs() = " + output.getNumArgs());` which produces an irrelevant output. And this is to be expected as just being an expression doesn't guarantee you'll have a valid `getNumArgs` output. The proper field to query is `getNumBound` as is done two lines later.